Solve ill-conditioned linear systems
Consider the following linear system of equations :
$$Ax = b$$
When solving this system using MATLAB, I found that the condition number of matrix
$A$ is extremely large, indicating that the system is ill-conditioned. Some characteristics of the system are as follows:

Condition number of $A$: 2.715e+06
Determinant of $A$: 0.51958

I have attempted several methods, including least squares, normalization, and regularization, but none have produced satisfactory results in terms of accuracy. The matrix $A$ and $b$ is currently stored as double type, and I have also tried using vpa to control the number of significant digits, but it was in vain. Are there any effective methods to solve this system, or is it possible to identify and eliminate highly correlated row vectors to ensure the accuracy of the remaining solutions?
Matlab data ‘.mat’:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlQCuPoSp7emgaNizYy43ea4fhgecg?e=vd3ubh
MATLAB CODE:
load("cal_linear_equations.mat");
DET_A=det(A_coeff);
Cond_A=cond(A_coeff);
Sol_real=A_coeff\b_coeff;
Error=A_coeff*Sol_real-b_coeff;
max(abs(Error));


I have not looked at your Matlab data, but generally if you have a sparse matrix, preconditioning is one of the best effective ways. Did you try it?

This matrix is dense. But I also am trying preconditioning to reduce the number of conditions.

What are the dimensions of your system ?

Removing highly correlated rows is basically the same thing as doing a low-rank approximation via a truncated SVD, so that may be a more robust way of conditioning

@JeanMarie The size of matrix A is 112 by 112.

What is $| Ax - b | / | b |$? Pretty small I’d bet.

Let $x$ denote the true solution of $Ax=b$ and let $\hat{x}$ denote the computed solution returned by our computer. By definition, the corresponding error $e$ is given by $$e = x - \hat{x}$$ and the residual is given by $r = b - A\hat{x}$. By definition, the normwise relative backward error $\eta(\hat{x})$ is given by $$\eta(\hat{x}) = \inf \{ \epsilon > 0 \: \exists \Delta A, \Delta b \: : \: (A+\Delta A)\hat{x} = b + \Delta b \wedge \|\Delta A\| \leq \epsilon \|A\| \wedge \|\Delta b\| \leq \epsilon \|b\| \}$$
It is possible to show that $$\eta(\hat{x}) = \frac{\|r\|}{\|A\|\|\hat{x}\| + \|b\|}.$$
Consult Higham's book "Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms" for the proof.
I have computed $\hat{x}$ using the backslash operator in MATLAB. Using the 2-norm, I find that $$\eta_2(\hat{x}) = \frac{\|r\|_2}{\|A\|_2\|\hat{x}\|_2 + \|b\|_2}\approx 8 \times 10^{-18}$$
This is far smaller than the unit roundoff in double precision and therefore much better than we have a right to expect. For the normwise relative forward error we have the bound
$$ \frac{\|x-\hat{x}\|_2}{\|x\|_2} \lesssim 2 \kappa_2(A) \eta_2(\hat{x}) \approx 4 \times 10^{-11}.$$
You can improve marginally upon these figures using iterative refinement but in reality you up against the limitations imposed by the use of double precision arithmetic. If you really need better accuracy, then you have to find a computer with a smaller unit roundoff or use an arbitrary precision library.
 I had an extra look at your matrix. It presents several features that are of  interest to me. It has 2 large singular values and 4 small and the rest are essentially 1.

This is unusual in my experience and not typical of 'bad' matrices. A surface plot of the matrix reveals are the large entries are concentrated in a few small islands that form an pleasing pattern.

Please tell us more about the origins of your matrix or contact me directly via my email which you will find by examining my profile.
